# What does hallucinatee signify grammatically?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, nouns

I was watching an Episode of the medical drama "House MD". When there was this conversation:

> House: I never called Wilson by his name.
>   Jack: Oh, yeah, right. The hallucinator is going to tell the hallucinatee what happened.
>   House: You’re not the hallucinatee, Wilson was the hallucinatee.

Is hallucinatee here a noun? The things you are hallucinating?
Is it some kind of special noun construction from the noun "Hallucination"? So, the hallucination is the act of hallucinating things, the hallucinatee is the things you are hallucinating.

Like for example, calling is the act of call, and caller is the one doing the call, can we say "callee" to describe the thing being called by applying the same logic of hallucinatee? What is this process called in Grammar? Or is it special case for "hallucinatee".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hallucinatee* is a word that's formed from grammar rules involving the suffix [**ee**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/EE), which can have two different senses:

> [Merriam-Webster]

> **-ee** noun suffix (1)
> Definition of *-ee* (Entry 2 of 3)
> 1 : recipient or beneficiary of (a specified action)
> // appoin*tee*
> // grant*ee*
> 2 : person furnished with (a specified thing)
> // patent*ee*
> 3 : person that performs (a specified action)
> // escap*ee*

> **-ee** noun suffix (2)
> Definition of *-ee* (Entry 3 of 3)
> 1 : one associated with
> // barg*ee*
> 2 : a particular especially small kind of
> // boot*ee*
> 3 : one resembling or suggestive of
> // goat*ee*

So, in theory, a *hallucinatee* could be one of two things:

- A person who has taken some kind of drug, or fallen ill, and has been afflicted with a hallucination.
- The subject of somebody *else's* hallucination.

But, additionally, the suffix [**or**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/or) also has a meaning:

> [Merriam-Webster]

> **-or** noun suffix (1)
> Definition of *-or* (Entry 7 of 8)
> : one that does a (specified) thing
> // grant*or*

Since both are used in the example sentence, the meaning is apparent from context:

> The hallucinator <sup>(the person who is hallucinating)</sup>
> is going to tell
> the hallucinatee <sup>(the person who is being hallucinated about)</sup>
> what happened.

In short, it's like this:

> I (the hallucinator) had a hallucination. In this hallucination, I saw you (the hallucinatee) struck by a car while going to work. When I saw you, I had to tell you—just in case.

Both words are nouns.

---

Note that some verbs get *er* added to them rather than *or*:

> The *caller* called the *callee*.

And, yes, it's correct to assume that you can add *ee*.

---

Note the additional confusion from all of the above:

- We say *caller*, not *callor*, for somebody who makes a call.
- We say *escapee* for a person who performs an escape, not for a person who has had an escape performed upon them or for them.
- I could be a *hallucinatee* of some bad food I ate (as a victim, the hallucination was inflicted upon me), but I could also be a *hallucinator* (somebody who hallucinates). It depends on how you look at it. In fact, I could be both at the same time. And it could get even worse if, in my hallucination, I saw myself. Then I would additionally be the *hallucinatee* of my hallucination. Thus, I could be described in three different senses with two words.

These different applications of suffixes to different verbs and in difference circumstances make it difficult to understand a general rule. English, unfortunately, is full of many such exceptions and inconsistencies.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed & in-depth answer!

Comment: I think escapee isn’t that much of a deviation, because multiple people may be involved in the escape who are not themselves imprisoned, but you would only use escapee to describe the person who was “escaped” from prison, and not the outside accomplices.